# jquery toggle dynamic height

Tags: jquery, height, toggle

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cUZpP/)

I've created left panel and give it auto height through jquery .height();. Its all working fine but if you collapsed it by clicking on arrow button, then you will see the icons underthe white box will also overflow to the left panel. I want that when i click on collapsed button to collapse then white box reduce so that pink icons not overflow. Any helo would be greatly appreciable thanks...

Comment: but i also want that the left panel stays on window it will not have scroll

Comment: add `$(".left-content-accounts").height(bodyheight - $(".social_icos").height() -28 -18);` after `$('.left-content').toggleClass('collapsed');` is this the way you want? But accept some answer...

Comment: thanks it helped me alot but not completely, but I'm working on it.